# How to increase sample frequency of dataset (reshape, interpolate?) and fill the Nan values with means

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation, reshape

I have a dataset with an uneven sample frequency as seen on this subset:

```
time    date              x     y   id      nn1                 nn2              
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   234   236 4909    22.02271554554524   38.2099463490856    
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   251   222 4911    22.02271554554524   46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   231   244 4909    30.4138126514911    41.617304093369626
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   252   222 4911    30.4138126514911    46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   207   210 4900    41.617304093369626  46.57252408878007
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   234   250 4909    33.28663395418648   48.82622246293481
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   206   210 4900    47.53945729601885   48.82622246293481
3   2019-09-17 08:43:09   252   222 4911    38.28837943815329   47.53945729601885
3   2019-09-17 08:43:09   206   210 4900    40.718546143004666  47.53945729601885
3   2019-09-17 08:43:09   223   247 4909    38.28837943815329   40.718546143004666
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   206   210 4900    35.4682957019364    47.53945729601885
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   229   237 4909    27.459060435491963  35.4682957019364
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   252   222 4911    27.459060435491963  47.53945729601885
5   2019-09-17 08:43:12   226   241 4909    30.805843601498726  38.01315561749642
5   2019-09-17 08:43:12   251   223 4911    30.805843601498726  44.94441010848846
5   2019-09-17 08:43:12   209   207 4900    38.01315561749642   44.94441010848846
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   251   222 4911    34.20526275297414   44.598206241955516
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   224   243 4909    34.20526275297414   39.0    
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   209   207 4900    39.0                44.598206241955516
7   2019-09-17 08:43:14   251   222 4911    33.421549934136806  45.5411901469428
7   2019-09-17 08:43:14   225   243 4909    33.421549934136806  39.81205847478876
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   225   245 4909    34.713109915419565  41.23105625617661
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   209   207 4900    41.23105625617661   44.598206241955516    
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   251   222 4911    34.713109915419565  44.598206241955516   
9   2019-09-17 08:43:16   209   207 4900    37.20215047547655   48.46648326421054
9   2019-09-17 08:43:16   254   225 4911    25.942243542145693  48.46648326421054
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   206   207 4900    41.182520563948     67.26812023536856
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   242   227 4909    30.805843601498726  41.182520563948
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   272   220 4911    30.805843601498726  67.26812023536856
```

I want to reshape the data set into even 0.25 Seconds intervals (increasing the sample frequency to 4 fps) and fill the Nan Values with average values of the given second. I fail with interpolating and reshaping, is there anyone that can help?? Also, the ID has to stay the same. I deeply appreciate!

Comment: What do you mean increasing frequency of sample and interpolating in this context? It would be better if you can provide the sample desired output.

Comment: What does _I fail with interpolating and reshaping_ mean, exactly? There's practically nothing to work with here.

Comment: Hey, sorry i understand the confusion and tried to reformulate it in a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460804/how-to-reshape-and-interpolate-df-into-even-time-intervals-and-fill-the-nan-valu

Comment: You should not be duplicating your own question but [edit] the original version. Please do so.