# How to reshape and interpolate df into even time intervals and fill the Nan values with means

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, interpolation, reshape

I have a dataset with an uneven time intervals (for example time 3 is missing):

```
time    date              x     y   id      nn1                 nn2              
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   234   236 4909    22.02271554554524   38.2099463490856    
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   251   222 4911    22.02271554554524   46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   231   244 4909    30.4138126514911    41.617304093369626
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   252   222 4911    30.4138126514911    46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   207   210 4900    41.617304093369626  46.57252408878007
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   234   250 4909    33.28663395418648   48.82622246293481
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   206   210 4900    47.53945729601885   48.82622246293481
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   206   210 4900    35.4682957019364    47.53945729601885
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   229   237 4909    27.459060435491963  35.4682957019364
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   252   222 4911    27.459060435491963  44.598206241955516  
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   251   222 4911    34.20526275297414   44.598206241955516
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   224   243 4909    34.20526275297414   39.0    
6   2019-09-17 08:43:13   209   207 4900    39.0                44.598206241955516
7   2019-09-17 08:43:14   251   222 4911    33.421549934136806  45.5411901469428
7   2019-09-17 08:43:14   225   243 4909    33.421549934136806  39.81205847478876
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   225   245 4909    34.713109915419565  41.23105625617661
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   209   207 4900    41.23105625617661   44.598206241955516    
8   2019-09-17 08:43:15   251   222 4911    34.713109915419565  44.598206241955516   
9   2019-09-17 08:43:16   209   207 4900    37.20215047547655   48.46648326421054
9   2019-09-17 08:43:16   254   225 4911    25.942243542145693  48.46648326421054
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   206   207 4900    41.182520563948     67.26812023536856
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   242   227 4909    30.805843601498726  41.182520563948
10  2019-09-17 08:43:18   272   220 4911    30.805843601498726  67.26812023536856
```

I want to reshape the data set into even 1 Seconds intervals and fill the Nan Values with average values of, lets say the second before. Is there anyone that can help??

Also, any idea of what to do with the Id's in this case? Otherwise, for now, they can be ignored. I deeply appreciate!

The desired output is something like this (Even time intervals:

```
time    date              x     y   id      nn1                 nn2              
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   234   236 4909    22.02271554554524   38.2099463490856    
0   2019-09-17 08:43:06   251   222 4911    22.02271554554524   46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   231   244 4909    30.4138126514911    41.617304093369626
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   252   222 4911    30.4138126514911    46.57252408878007
1   2019-09-17 08:43:07   207   210 4900    41.617304093369626  46.57252408878007
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   234   250 4909    33.28663395418648   48.82622246293481
2   2019-09-17 08:43:08   206   210 4900    47.53945729601885   48.82622246293481
3   2019-09-17 08:43:09   Nan   Nan 4909    Nan                 Nan    
3   2019-09-17 08:43:09   Nan   Nan 4911    Nan                 Nan
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   206   210 4900    35.4682957019364    47.53945729601885
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   229   237 4909    27.459060435491963  35.4682957019364
4   2019-09-17 08:43:10   252   222 4911    27.459060435491963  47.53945729601885
5   2019-09-17 08:43:11   Nan   Nan 4911    Nan                 Nan
5   2019-09-17 08:43:11   Nan   Nan 4909    Nan                 Nan    
5   2019-09-17 08:43:11   Nan   Nan 4900    Nan                 Nan
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by even intervals here, can you please elaborate

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Reshaping or filling with NaN?

Comment: Both parts unfortunately. In the original dataset, for instance, time 3 is missing. So I would like to extend my original datasets with filling these time gaps with average numbers from, lets say, the previous 5 data points. The tricky part is that the new data lines for missing time windows should take the means of previous IDs into consideration, so that we generate values for the IDs present  in the previous data lines.